# BlowFish Encryption: Cannot decrypt cipher to original plaintext

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, openssl, blowfish

I'm using OpenSSL BlowFish and encountering something very strange. My functions are below:

```
char* BFEncrypt(char* key, char* text)
{
     char ivec[EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH] = {0};
     int len = strlen(text);
     char *cipher = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
     int *num = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
     *num = 0;
     BF_KEY *bfkey = (BF_KEY*)malloc(sizeof(BF_KEY));
     BF_set_key(bfkey, strlen(key), key);
     BF_cfb64_encrypt(text, cipher, len, bfkey, ivec, num, BF_ENCRYPT);
     cipher[len] = '\0';
     free(num);
     free(bfkey);
     return cipher; 
}

char* BFDecrypt(char* key, char* cipher)
{
     char ivec[EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH] = {0};
     int len = strlen(cipher);
     char *text = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
     int *num = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
     *num = 0;
     BF_KEY *bfkey = (BF_KEY*)malloc(sizeof(BF_KEY));
     BF_set_key(bfkey, strlen(key), key);
     BF_cfb64_encrypt(cipher, text, len, bfkey, ivec, num, BF_DECRYPT);
     text[len] = '\0';
     free(num);
     free(bfkey);
     return text; 
}
```

If I did something as below in a function, I can obtain the right plaintext from decryption:

```
char *plainText1;
char *key1;
//initialize those pointers
char *cipher1 = BFEncrypt(key1, plainText1);
char *temp = BFDecrypt(key1, cipher1); //here I test that temp is equal to plainText1
```

However, in a different function, if I only invoke the BFDecrypt, I would not be able to get the same plaintext before:

```
//somehow I stored the cipher1 above in my disk and read it 
char *cipher2; //store cipher1
char *key2;// key2 is equal to key1
char *plaintext2 = BFDecrypct(key2, cipher2); //Here is the problem!!!!! plaintext2 is not equal to plaintext1
```

The confusing part is, even if key2 and cipher2 is exactly the same as key1 and cipher1 , plaintext2 is completely different with plaintext1. Could anyone give me a hint, I stuck on this for a long time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any particular reason you're still using blowfish in 2014?

Comment: @CodesInChaos just a homework. I know it's out of date.

Comment: Fixed. Nothing wrong in blowfish, forgot terminate for key2.

Comment: @TonyLic If you have a solution for your problem, you should format it as an answer and accept it yourself, so that the question appears answered.